# How to take wavelet transform of sparse input data

Tags: wavelet

I have a sparse dataset indexed by nanoseconds. Storing the dataset in a discrete fashion would take too much memory. I'd like to take a wavelet transform and I'd like it to be relatively fast. The dataset has about 100,000 dirac deltas in it.

Is this possible?

Thanks!
James

Comment: Welcome. I do not understand the link between your question and the tags you have chosen.  Then, the purpose of using a wavelet transform on already sparse data is not fully clear to me. Could you please elaborate on the objective?

Comment: Sorry, the tags were from a draft of something else. I've fixed it!

Comment: What is the typical of each stride of data? Shall we assume that the deltas are of constant of variable amplitude? Are the other samples zeros, or is there noise?

Comment: The data has a fractal quality to it. There can be short periods where it changes a large amount in amplitude and the frequency of points varies with those changes. The data spans 6 hours and is marked with nanoseconds (or microseconds works too). Outside of these 100k events, everything else is 0 (in delta space). The 100k events represent a change in the underlying value. I have 1 million different time series all like this and I want to take a wavelet transform of all of them in an efficient manner (on a distributed cluster).